# 'You bust your lip on spodie odie' and other song lyrics

Tags: meaning, lyrics

I'm having trouble understanding some phrases in Jack White's song "Just One Drink [lyrics](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/jackwhite/justonedrink.html).

I especially am confused by

1. "You bust your lip on wine spodie odie"

What does this mean?

I also need help with

2. "gets me closer" to..what? To you in this lyrics possibly? Or is that some saying?
3. "roll over" and "turn over" out there, Do you think they're same sense? As in fall by alcohol?

4."put a fork in the road" is like, "let's make a different in the road(as in get married)"?

From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_in_the_road_%28metaphor%29) link it's a metaphor for making a big decision.

I know there is more than one way to interpret song lyrics, but I appreciate if you help me to grab the image.

:added:
I'm sorry now I see this post doesn't match to this site's concept.
But before I close this thread, can anyone direct me what website should I post this kind of question? very active is better. Although this question also doesn't match to the concept here, please.

Comment: If it were possible to explain these lyrics in terms of English idioms, I'd say we should keep the question open. But they're idiosyncratic musings, so it's anybody's guess what they might mean, and I will also vote to close.

Comment: I am also voting to close, not because the source of the question is song lyrics, but because there are multiple questions here. I think you could ask a specific question about #1. [Spodie](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=spodie) is a slang term, and the rhyming "spodie odie" is an English pattern we can explain.  I would love to see you break this into individual questions where you have done some research on the words in the line you're asking about (search for definitions).

Comment: @mr.fishhead I would read what ColleenV says just above. List several questions, each  asking about a single phrase. Include in each question  the research you have done. The most productive phrase  seems to be *spodie odie* because *spodie* is a known slang term. The other phrases are ambiguous, and **no other site can tell you otherwise**.

Comment: @mr.fishhead I don't know of many websites that will answer multiple questions at once. You could try ask.com or ask yahoo or wherever those sites are called.

Comment: You could ask in [chat] - some folks there might be interested in discussing the lyrics. This is one of those questions that's going to be difficult to get a definitive answer to unless you talk to Jack White.

Comment: SpottieOttieDopaliscious is a song by Outkast from the 90s. It means "very attractive." Jack White is saying "*I want my* spottie ottie" BTW ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXmqauitBkM @ 4:30 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lyrics in this song are hard to interpret. The phrases you mention in 2 and 3 are open ended and can have multiple meanings. Possibly the songwriter does this on purpose. This is art, not a scientific treatise.

Yes, a 'fork in the road' means 'a deciding moment in life or history when a major choice of options is required'  (Wikipedia) but to *'put* a fork in the road' is ambiguous.

As for *wine, [spodie odie](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=spodieodie)*,  it probably means very cheap wine. Unless Jack is actually singing *[spotieottie](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/spottieottie)*, which means a beautiful girl. I mention that only because some lyric websites say *spottieottie*; I've not listened to the song myself. And by the way, actually seeing how the song is sung can sometimes clear up textual ambiguities (body language is 75% of communication and all that).

See [Genius dot com](http://genius.com/Jack-white-just-one-drink-lyrics) for some interpretations, including the one   that the song is not about a woman but about a car.

That last one may appear ridiculous, but who knows? People love their cars.

On the other hand the poem by E. E.  Cummings, ["she being Brand"](http://writersalmanac.publicradio.org/index.php?date=2002%2F10%2F14) is,  on the surface,  about a car but is actually about making love to a woman.